# Why does prepend method removes the HTML from where it actually was

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a KeyBoard plugin, which I am trying to edit. So to change the Layout of the plugin, I wanted to make it to get the full screen covered. I am in the beginning of the process, so I thought of removing the HTML codes from the bottom and just pasting them right below the `body` element of the document. This way, I would make a use of the screen properties as well as the position property. Like this

```
$('#vboard').css('width', screen.width);
$('#vboard').css('position', 'absolute');
```

etc.

#### What I did

I used the prepend method, to append it to the top of the body element childs. Here is my code

```
var vbrd = $('#vboard');
/* Paste it inside the HTML directory */
$('body').prepend(vbrd);
```

#### What I expected

What I expected was, that it would just create a new Node (Child) of the body element, and would keep the HTML in the body element where it first belonged to. I am using ASP.NET Web Page, so every page gets created in

```
<div> <!-- Inside the body element -->
  <!--Here-->
</div>
```

#### What happened

What happened was something like this

[image]

What happened was, that it got appened to the body, as I was trying to do so. But at the same time, it removed the HTML nodes from the element where it was placed.

Is that expected? Because everywhere I search, it tells me to use `.remove()` method to remove the elements too. But in this scene it wasn't required.

Comment: `$('body')` != `$('#body')`.  The former is the `<body>` tag.  The latter is your `<div id="body">`.

Comment: I know, I am using ASP.NET which would create the elements under the div element. :) Just what we call `Layout` :)

Comment: I only bring it up because your question is a little confusing regarding where you are trying to append a node.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry! I must remove it if its confusing...I have removed it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. It is expected.

Prepend puts the element where you tell it to put it, and the element can't be in two places at once.

It does not clone it. [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) does.

Answer (score 0):

That's the way it works in jQuery, the way it works in the bare DOM APIs, and the way it's documented by both. If you want to insert a *copy* rather than moving the original then use `$('body').prepend(vbrd.clone())`;